# I'm getting an error but I can't resolve this error

Tags: javascript, node.js

MyCode;

```
eventHandler.js

const reqEvent = async(event) => require(`../events/${event}`);

module.exports = async(client) => {
    client.on("ready", () => reqEvent("ready")(client, "message"));
    client.on("message", () => reqEvent("message"));
}
```

```
y client definition

const client = new Discord.Client({
  intents: [
    Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
    Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS,
    Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
    Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS,
    Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_VOICE_STATES
  ]
});
```

Error;

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "listener" argument must be of type function. Received an instance of Promise
    at checkListener (node:events:128:3)
    at _addListener (node:events:423:3)
    at Client.addListener (node:events:487:10)
at module.exports (/app/util/eventHandler.js:5:12)
at Object.<anonymous> (/app/index.js:15:34)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
```

I can't solve this error, can anyone help with the solution?
I Used Google Translate. I'm Sorry If I Have Any Mistakes.

Comment: What exactly is the intent of this?: `reqEvent("ready")(client, "message")`

Comment: Why add `async`? You're not using `await` inside these functions, so it's useless

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
module.exports = async(client) => {
    client.on("message", (message)=> {
       reqEvent(message.content);
   });
};
```